# Use java classes in liferay theme?

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, velocity, liferay-theme

Is there any way to use .java Classes in liferay theme? I want to use a class of java to converting dates. So how can I include java classes to my liferay 6 theme and use it on `portal_normal.vm` velocity?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible to have java code within liferay theme.

You already have `dateUtil` reference within velocity context to have some date utilities. Refer to `DateUtil_IW` class for method list.

Inject new util class in velocity it's quite complex to explain, you have to build an ext plugin. It's better to build a portlet plugin and embed it within theme.

Comment: I dont know why this is the accepted answer as it obviously is wrong. I had java classes within themes for a whole while until dxp came out. Now you will have to use something called Templating Context Contributor, I guess. Have a look: https://dev.liferay.com/de/develop/reference/-/knowledge_base/7-0/template-context-contributor

Answer (score 4):

Well, You can certainly achieve it, and I don't think it is complex. Step by step instructions to [call your java class from theme vm](https://www.liferay.com/web/raymond.auge/blog/-/blogs/custom-velocity-tools-and-liferay-6-0) are given [here](https://www.liferay.com/web/raymond.auge/blog/-/blogs/custom-velocity-tools-and-liferay-6-0). You can also use Liferay's `dateUtil` as @Daniele mentioned -or- go though [Velocity reference](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/user-guide.html) if any of the advanced functions suit your requirements..